# From Pandas Dataframe to pyodbc (Azure SQL DB) using sqlalchemy: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, pyodbc, simple-salesforce

I'm trying to load Salesforce data to Azure SQL Database incrementally by launching a Python script on Azure Databricks.

Since I'm not able to install Devart ODBC in Azure Databricks, I'm trying to use simple_salesforce to get data from salesforce:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, SalesforceLogin, SFType
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, Text, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

sf = Salesforce(password = password, username=username, security_token=jeton)
rep_qr = "SELECT SOMETHING FROM Account WHERE CONDITION"
soql = prep_qr.format(','.join(field_names))
results = sf.query_all(soql)['records']
```

I get the following result (an example):

```
[OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Account'), ('url', '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/0014K000009aoU3QAI')])), ('Id', XY1), (Name, Y), (Date, 2020-11-24T09:16:17.000+0000)])]
```

Then I converted the output to a pandas Dataframe:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(sf.query_all(soql)['records'])
results.drop(columns=['attributes'], inplace=True) #to keep only the columns
```

I got something like this (just an example):

| Id | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XY1 | Y | 2020-11-24T09:16:17.000+0000 |

In order to ingest this data into Azure SQL Database I have used "sqlalchemy" to convert the Dataframe into sql, then pyodbc will take in charge the insertion part into the destination (Azure SQL Database), as shown bellow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) #just to remove the index from dataframe

#Creating the engine from and pyodbc which is connected to Azure SQL Database:
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus \
                (r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)
df.to_sql('account',engine_azure,if_exists='append', index=False)
```

But I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I think the problem is the library simple_salesforce brigns the date/time in this format:

```
2020-11-24T09:16:17.000+0000
```

But in Azure SQL Database it should be something like this:

```
2020-11-24T09:16:17.000
```

The problem here is I'm loading the tables dynamically (I don't even know the tables nor the columns that I'm loading) the reason why I can't cast these data type, I need a way to pass datatype to pyodbc automatically.

What can you recommend please ?

Thanks,

Comment: If you are appending to existing tables (`if_exists="append"`) then you can reflect the table metadata and see which columns are datetime, datetime2, etc.. If you are creating new tables then the columns will be created as varchar/nvarchar and those strings could be converted to proper datetime (etc.) values later if necessary.

Comment: Can you please show us how can we reflect the table's metadata ?

Comment: Something like `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='account'`

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem here is that I'm trying to automate the process. I'm ingesting around 100 tables from salesforce (and each one contains tens of columns). The reason why I'm looking for a method (if it exists) that casts data types automatically from the ones in dataframe to the ones needed in pyodbc

Comment: When simple_salesforce returns a datetime value does it [1] always come back as a string (`str`), and [2] always end with `+0000`?

Comment: Yes we developed a specific function for the conversion. We tought there is an option to handle at the APIs level! Thank and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date/time values are consistently returned as strings of the form `2020-11-24T11:22:33.000+0000` then you can use pandas' `.apply()` method to convert the strings to the `2020-11-24 11:22:33.000` format that SQL Server will accept:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (1, "2020-11-24T11:22:33.000+0000"),
        (2, None),
        (3, "2020-11-24T12:13:14.000+0000"),
    ],
    columns=["id", "dtm"],
)
print(df)
"""console output:
   id                           dtm
0   1  2020-11-24T11:22:33.000+0000
1   2                          None
2   3  2020-11-24T12:13:14.000+0000
"""

df["dtm"] = df["dtm"].apply(lambda x: x[:23].replace("T", " ") if x else None)
print(df)
"""console output:
   id                      dtm
0   1  2020-11-24 11:22:33.000
1   2                     None
2   3  2020-11-24 12:13:14.000
"""

df.to_sql(
    table_name,
    engine,
    index=False,
    if_exists="append",
)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    pprint(conn.execute(sa.text(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}")).fetchall())
"""console output:
[(1, datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 24, 11, 22, 33)),
 (2, None),
 (3, datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 24, 12, 13, 14))]
"""
```